# Django - Filter queryset by another queryset through related field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose I have the two models below and I want to get a queryset of all developers that have games where the platform field matches a certain value. How would I go about that?

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Unknown")

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    developer = models.ForeignKey(Developer, related_name="games", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I tried a few approached but can't seem to figure anything out that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can query this with:

```
Developer.objects.filter(games__platform='name-of-platform').distinct()
```

Without the [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct), the *same* developer will be returned multiple times, if they developed multiple `Game`s for the same platform. If that is not a problem, you can of course omit the `.distinct()`.